# Oracle VirtualBox Ubuntu OS can't open my virtual machine even I enter the password correctly

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu OS to convert my Python file to an APK file. I created a virtual machine that has Ubuntu OS but I closed the virtual machine and I can't reopen it because I think there is a problem with virtual machine, it doesn't accept the password.

I'm sure that I type the correct password because when I type the correct password, nothing happens. It just send me back to the login page but when I type the wrong password, this happens:
[image: wrong password]

I know it's a bit irrelevant question for stackoverflow but I don't know where else I can ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There existed some issues with the login screen loop in older versions of Ubuntu.

To circumvent the UI login you can try

- Ctrl + Alt + F3
- login there
- run: startx

Comment: After that, should it open directly my Ubuntu desktop? I stuck in the terminal.

Comment: You open a terminal with "Ctrl + Alt + F3", you get the login prompt. Type in your username and password. You should than be logged in and get a prompt. 
If this login works, we know that it is an UI issue with a login loop.
Then you should be able to type startx and press enter.

Where are you stuck in the terminal?

Comment: It's open now, it worked.